# What are the guidelines for asking proof of scripture's validity or idea of scriptures?

Tags: discussion, scope, suggestions

On this site I have seen questions like

> "gods"what is the ***most striking, conspicious and visible proof of the
> presence of God?***
>
> ***If reincarnation is false***, doesn't that make the whole argument of
> Bhagavad Gita invalid?

Now, *I asked a question
Prove me existence of ghosts citing bhagvad gita 9.25 , it was deleted by mod(pandya)
So, first I want to ask why?*

Next ***I want to know can there be guideline set for asking of proofs*** because one can't prove how heaven and hell exist in after life or prove that gangawater cures sin in scientific or mathematical manner.

***So can guidelines be given for proof type questions?***

Comment: Reconsidering it.